# Cannot execute scp with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get-modidy-send a file from/to a remote host.
It's Windows 10, By the way.

I've reduced code to be easier:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>

bool getFile(QStringList &logTextList)
{
    QProcess scp;

    scp.start( "scp", QStringList() );
    if( scp.waitForStarted(1000) )
    {
        if( scp.waitForFinished(10000) == true )
        {
            if( scp.exitCode() == 0 )
            {
                logTextList.append(scp.readAllStandardError());
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            logTextList.append("Not finished");
    }
    else
        logTextList.append( "Not Started" );
    logTextList.append( scp.readAllStandardError() );
    logTextList.append( scp.readAllStandardOutput() );
    logTextList.append( QString("Exitcode = %1\n").arg(scp.exitCode()) );
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QStringList logTextList;

    getFile(logTextList);

    return a.exec();
}
```

QProcess never starts with "scp" or even "dir" (remember, it's windows 10 host)
But with "cmd" or "ping" command works.
Also tried to execute "cmd" and write to stdin "scp". But command prompt reports that "scp" is an unkknown command.

[EDIT] Just found that "dir" is not an external executable. So, need to be execute within "cmd.exe". And works.
But "scp" still doesn't.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah.  Very likely you don't have the 'scp' command on your system, or for some reason, command prompt can't find it.  If you can't execute it from cmd.exe, you won't be able to via QProcess.

Comment: powershell command for install `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client*`

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn process by name it is searched in all paths in `PATH` environment variable, if it's not there it wont work.

You can fix it by adding scp path to `PATH` temporary or permanently before starting your application.

Or you can spawn process using full path:

```cpp
QString command = "scp";
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
command = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\scp.exe";
#endif
scp.start(command, {});
```

Or you can spawn scp through shell with modified environment:

```
QProcess scp;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
QString PATH = env.value("PATH") + ";C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin";
env.insert("PATH", PATH);
scp.setProcessEnvironment(env);
scp.start("cmd",{"/c","scp"});
```

Comment: I was unable to found scp.exe or scp.com file anywhere in PATH directories.